# iOSで大きなデータを処理するアプリにおけるメモリ管理の注意点

Tags: ios, メモリ管理

お世話になっております。漠然とした質問になってしまい恐縮ですが、次のような問題の相談をチームの人から受けて返答に窮しております。

「100MBを超えるデータをメモリに持つと、iOSがプロセスをすぐにkillする」

こうなることを防ぐために自分で調べた結果、次のような対応をすればよいらしいとわかりました。

- UIViewControllerのdidReceiveMemoryWarningメソッド内で適切に不要なビューを開放する（nilを代入する？）
- AppDelegateのapplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning内でモデルなどVC以外で使用しているメモリのうち不要なものを開放する
- UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification通知を受け取り適切に対処する

参考：メモリ効率の向上に 関するガイドライン（https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/MemoryUsage.pdf）

また、GitHubでソースコードを見られるアプリのコードを見たのですが、
あまりメモリ管理が原因でiOSからkillされる状況に対処してあるアプリは多くありませんでした。

## 質問点

これ以外の点でiOS側からプロセスを止められないためにすべき対策があればご指摘くださると幸いです。今までiOSのプログラムを書いていて、あまりそのようなケースにあたったことがなく、また入門書などでもあまり見ない話題です。

なお、その相談してきた人の作っているアプリはカメラから画像を取得して処理するものです。画像のマッチングなどに多量のデータをメモリに持つ必要があるとのことです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 私の経験から言うと、`didReceiveMemoryWarning`などが呼ばれてからあたふたしても大抵は手遅れで、遅かれ早かれそのアプリは落とされます。そもそも **_100MBを超えるデータをメモリに持つ_** ようなコードは書かない、と言うのが大原則でしょう。 **_画像のマッチングなどに多量のデータをメモリに持つ必要_** とのことですが、PCやグラフィックワークステーションのように大量のメモリリソースを当てにした画像処理アルゴリズムをそのまま適用しようとしているのではないでしょうか。チームの画像処理部の担当者に「iOSではそのように大量のメモリリソースは使えないからもっと省メモリの処理方法を考えるべき」と言うのがまずすべきことのように思われます。最悪アプリの要件・仕様自体を見直す必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: そうですね、私もその意見に賛成です。経験則は非常に参考になります。ありがとうございます。アルゴリズムについては私もそう答えたのですが、その担当者はアルゴリズムではなくiOSのメモリ管理でなんとかする方法を探しているとのことです。補足ですが、そのアプリは（ぼかして説明になりますが）iPhoneのカメラで見ているものをリアルタイムで解析するものです。逐一入力があるとデータをサーバ側に送るのが難しいのかもしれませんが、私がそのアプリの設計者ならデータの処理はクラウドやIoTの考え方を取り入れると思います。

Comment: 私の部下なら「どんなすごいことができても本番環境で動かないコードはただのゴミだ」と言って叱るところなんですが…。とりあえず事実から。・iOS10のターゲットハードのメモリは(最小)1GB、iOS9までターゲットなら512MBしかありません、・iOSにはデマンドページングのような機構はありません(あってもリアルタイム画像処理には…)、先のメモリ容量をシステム・サービス・バックグラウンドで動いているアプリ、そしてあなたのアプリで分け合うことになります、・メモリ不足で落ちるようなアプリはApp Storeの審査に合格しません、・あなたのアプリが大量のメモリを要求したせいでシステム全体でメモリ不足に陥る場合、`didReceiveMemoryWarning`等さえ呼ばれずいきなりアプリが落とされることもあります。…と言うわけで、いわゆる画像処理そのもののアルゴリズムを見直すかどうかは別にして、画像処理部分のメソッドが省メモリのコーディングをしない限り解決はできません。Otsuka Makoto さんの書かれている回答は省メモリコーディングの定石の一つですが、メモリ使用量が千分の一以下になることもある一方で、全く効果のない場合もあります。とにかく画像処理部分のメモリ使用量そのものを減らさない限り解決はありえない、ことは担当者に伝えておくべきでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

100MB超のデータというのがどういうものなのか、どこで何をやってる時に Kill されているのかがわからないので、大量データをループで処理している最中に Kill されるというケースについてのお話です。
大量のデータをループで処理されるような場合、ループ内の処理を「autoreleasepool ブロックで囲む」のが定石かと思います。
使用言語が ObjCなのかSwiftなのかわからないのですが、ObjCなら

```
while true {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // 処理
    }
}
```

Swift なら

```
while true {
    autoreleasepool {
        // 処理
    }
}
```

です。